# HTML form autofill: is there a regex match against name attribute or should it be literal?

Tags: forms, autocomplete, attributes, autofill

I couldn't find out from specs that should the name attribute's value be literal or is it evaluated by regex or similar?

e.g. does it have to be **name="fname"** or can it be **name="userdetails[fname]"**?

Same goes for HTML5 related autocomplete attribute?

And is there differences between browsers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any text there.

What you mention about array (`userdetails[fname]`) - from point of view html it's usual string, but PHP interprets this string into an array.

Comment: That is true, but I'm concerned about how it might effect on autofill functionality? Or did you mean that any string will be compatible with autofill as long as it contains the specified autofill indentifier like fname, lname, email etc?

Comment: @user1271930 I don't think that these problems occur. Square brackets it is quite normal characters.

Comment: I don't that it is about character type but the content itself and how it is intepreted.

Comment: Chrome regex: first name: "first.*name|initials|fname|first$"
last name: "last.*name|lname|surname|last$|secondname|family.*name"
email:  "e.?mail"
address (line 1): "address.*line|address1|addr1|street"
zipcode: "zip|postal|post.*code|pcode|^1z$"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that there's no any intelligence / regex on these fields.

fname, lname do not work and only first_name and last_name worked on Chrome and Firefox.

So best is to have literal naming. Some sources suggested that there could be some kind of regex evaluation but at least I couldn't find anything reliable. But at least I found this https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute